# MS CRM 2011 Autonumbering

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In MSCRM 2011, there is out of the box auto numbering on several entities such as quotes, cases (incidents).

The 3 character prefix, e.g. QUO, CAS is followed by 5 digits, then 5 alphanumeric characters by default.

Looking at our CRM database, the references created have ranged from

CAS-00001-XXXXX 
up to 
CAS-97500-XXXXX

XXXXX is just 5 random chars and the numerical part above is incrementing one at a time chronologically and we're a little concerned what will happen when it reaches 99999. Does it automatically go back to the beginning but use a different 5 characters after the 2nd hyphen?

Our next approach is to make a console app to insert 100000 quotes into our database but would be good to avoid having to do this if someone knows exactly how it works. When I Google for it, I just get people's solutions for autonumbering with very little about how CRM's own numbering works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it reaches 99,999 it goes on to 100,000, when it reaches 999,999 it goes to 1,000,000

Source:

http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2014/09/crm-auto-numbering-what-happens-when.html

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find that page when looking so you are a saviour! Bit annoying it keeps going up in number as it means the 5 random characters after the 2nd hyphen are effectively pointless? Causes an issue for us as our destination system has limit length field for storing case numbers and we're already stripping out CAS and the hyphens. Think we'll need to implement our own numbering solution to replace this

Comment: you can always create a plugin that will strip out CAS and hyphens and put only the numbers in another field on the create event. So you will not need to implement an autonumbering solution. You can do also with a workflow in combination with a  custom workflow activity.

Comment: Yeah, this is what we've done - ended up just going for CAS-[5 random chars]-[5 random chars] so moving away from the numerical incremental approach.